# undefined method _path (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving the following error in my Rails app when I try to access a page that contains a form to create a post. I'm trying to implement a feature similar to Michael Hartl's Micropost feature in his sample app:

```
NoMethodError in Home#index
undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0xb5c70744>:0xb60013b8>
```

Here's the index view page that contains the code to insert the form:

```
<%= render 'shared/post_form' if user_signed_in? %>
```

_post_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Provide your network with a status update..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the Home controller:

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    #render :text => "Welcome #{current_user.email}!"
    @users = User.all
    @post = current_user.posts.build if signed_in?
  end
end
```

I can really use some help in reviewing the code. I'm staring at it and I need someone else to review it for me. I'm new to Rails so please forgive me if I did not provide the necessary information.

Additional information: I'm using the Devise gem to handle user authentication.

Thanks!

EDIT: I added the wrong controller.

EDIT 2:

Routes.rb file:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do

  #get "users/index"

  #get "users/show"



authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :posts
    end
  end
  resources :works
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

EDIT 3: Rake routes

```
root        /                              home#index
                    root        /                              home#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
          following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
          followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
              posts_user GET    /users/:id/posts(.:format)     users#posts
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                   works GET    /works(.:format)               works#index
                         POST   /works(.:format)               works#create
                new_work GET    /works/new(.:format)           works#new
               edit_work GET    /works/:id/edit(.:format)      works#edit
                    work GET    /works/:id(.:format)           works#show
                         PUT    /works/:id(.:format)           works#update
                         DELETE /works/:id(.:format)           works#destroy
           relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
            relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
```

Comment: `<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>` change to `<%= form_for(Post.new) do |f| %>`

Comment: The last comment does not solve the root issue. Rather than fully connecting Rails use of REST HTTP, it creates an Post object for that form. This becomes an issue when you use this form for Editing an already created object stored within @post. To get at the root of the problem, can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: Sorry, `<%= form_for Post.new ,:url => {:action => :create, :controller => :posts} do |f| %>` this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I added the right Home controller code and I also added the routes.rb code

Comment: you don't need the if signed in if you have a before filter of authenticate user

Comment: can you do a rake routes? it looks like it is going to your posts_path but your building in the home controller. you should have def new and def create

Comment: Added rake routes. Thanks for the assistance. Where should I define the new and create actions? In the Home controller?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add `resources :posts` in your `routes.rb` file in order for Rails to automatically create the `posts_path` helper for you.

Adding `resources :posts` will generate the proper RESTful routes for you to create, delete, update, and fetch `posts`. Take a look at the Ruby on Rails Guide for routing, specifically [this section here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) on routing and RESTful routes.

Comment: Hi Zajn, thank you very much for the reply. This worked. I didn't consider adding the resources :posts because Michael Hartl's tutorial seemed to leave it out (I don't understand why). I should have given this a try anyway! Your help, and everyone else that replied, is greatly appreciated!