# Ruby on Rails Undefined Method for simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, webforms, web

I have been facing a lot of troubles with the create view for my **Ruby on Rails** project. The model is called **grouponepage**.

Here is my new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @postings1314 do |r| %>
  <div>
    <%=@postings1314.label :firstName%>
    <%=@postings1314.text_field :firstName%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=@postings1314.label :lastName%>
    <%=@postings1314.text_field :lastName%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=@postings1314.label :age%>
    <%=@postings1314.text_field :age%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=@postings1314.label :bio%>
    <%=@postings1314.text_field :bio%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= @postings1314.submit %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

This is my grouponepostings_controller.rb:

```
class GrouponepostingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @postings1314 = Grouponepage.all
  end
  def show
    @posting1314singular = Grouponepage.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @postings1314 = Grouponepage.new
  end
end
```

And finally, the error occurs only when the view is rendered, showing:

```
Users/______/Desktop/TeenRecuiter/app/views/grouponepostings/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x007f9de8119850>:0x007f9de6fc4ca8>
```

Comment: do you have the simple-form gem on your gemfile?

Comment: I just checked and I didn't have that gem in my gemfie. Once I did fix that it gave me a new error reading: undefined method `grouponepages_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fee22985018>:0x007fee213b5698>

Comment: I did more reaserch on the error message and found the soultion at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300948/undefined-method-path-nomethoderror Thanks so much for your help @arieljuod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need add this gem
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

Run the following command to install it:

```
bundle install
```

Run the generator:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```